# MFC image visualizer for huge image

Tags: c++, opengl, mfc

What is the best way of rendering a big image (say, around 10k x 10k pixels) in an MFC window, with mouse events for moving and scaling, etc?

I thought of the following alternatives:

- an OpenGL context (is this possible?)
- loading and storing the image in a static buffer with some lib (OpenCV for instance) and continuously apply transformations (shift and scaling for the mouse events) <- this would imply huge computational costs?
- Any other alternative?

Comment: Are you creating a Bitmap? If so, you can use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183494(v=vs.85).aspx and yes, this comes with very big computational costs.

Comment: I do this in MFC using a Direct2D texture which is loaded dynamically from a moving window over a memory mapped file. The MMF contains the image pixels and the moving window and texture are sized to match the application window. Due to the normal Windows disk caching mechanisms, this works well even without SSD drives on images up to 32K x 24K pixels....

Comment: ... The MMF contains a pyramid of x2 downsampled versions of the image that are used for zooming - the application just maps over the most relevant downscaled level and uses a small amount of digital zoom (via GPU) to keep things smooth.

Comment: @RogerRowland that seems to be quite specific. Can you provide some code snippets or so?

Comment: @manatttta Sorry, it's a bit too big for snippets and it's a commercial application anyway, but the technique is quite common. The basics of the ideas (a virtual image surface and image pymarid) came from Microsoft's [HD View](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/groups/ivm/HDView/), which is now quite old. However, I would say that your target of 10K x 10K may even be "small" enough for a simpler application, given suitable graphics hardware.

Comment: @RogerRowland I see. Well I am actually dealing with 50kx50k images in some cases, I guess the OpenGL alternative would be quite heavy also?

Comment: @manatttta OpenGL or DirectX (2D or 3D), the principle is the same. Keep your large image on disk, map an MMF over the active (visible) part of it and load a texture from that. Then once you have that rendering ok, add panning by remapping the MMF view and reloading the texture. When you get that going, you'll see that the zooming uses the same techniques but needs a little optimisation to keep it smooth. Just displaying a big image at 1:1 with panning is really quite easy, so choose OpenGL or DirectX and start from there.

Comment: We had a 2D software in Windows that could run over 4 Engines: GDI, GDI+, Direct 2D and OpenGL. GDI proved to be the fastest on drawings. Derived from this observation, I recommend that you use it. I also recommend for you to create a Memory DC, do the drawing operations in there, and after transfer its contents to your View DC, by using BitBlt function.